# Error LNK2019 in a Makefile configuration type using a library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I was working on a [tutorial project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) I found on another website where it explains how to use Java inside a C++ project (this is just for context, isn't the important part). The project was working as it should. After that I wanted to copy the code to another project, but this time it was of **Makefile** config type. First I ran *nmake* command thinking that it might tell me where the file is, but I got an error instead: `NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified`, which I thought that there isn't one, and I have to make it. So I made a file and named it *Makefile* and inside I added only one line `JNILIB=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\lib\jvm.lib` that I thought I need. After that I ran *nmake* again, only this time I got back:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30141.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

But the problem still persists and that is `Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol`. This means I'm doing something wrong, but to be honest I don't know how to use **Makefile** which clearly shows (maybe I need to add more to the file, or what I wrote is wrong).

Can anyone help me get past this error? That is the only problem I have, how to tell it that I'm using that library from that location.

Comment: Could you show your makefile?

Comment: "So I made a file and named it Makefile and inside I added only one line JNILIB=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\lib\jvm.lib that I thought I need."

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with using `nmake`. Below is a test I did, putting the DLL in the same directory as cpp.

makefile:

```
foo: main.cpp
  cl main.cpp TestDll.lib
```

Comment: By the way, you may need to add your lib to the system environment.